# Python request fails from google cloud platform (app engine & cloud shell)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I have a very simple python http request which works on my local machine, but does not work in google app engine or from the google cloud shell. There must be config that is messing with the request, but I can't seem to find the problem.

I am using python 3.7

The code that causes the exception is the following (I have replaced the actual URL by example.com)

(The service I need to call is listening on port 6123)

```
import requests
myrequest = requests.get("http://example.com:6123/something?param=123")
```

The full error message I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 184, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0b242cd710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=6123): Max retries exceeded with url: /something?param=123 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0b242cd710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=6123): Max retries exceeded with url: /something?param=123 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0b242cd710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Comment: Do you have billing enabled? External requests are not allowed until billing is enabled. Without knowing the actual URL it's hard to determine what's wrong here.

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled.

Comment: If you are on Cloud Shell, what's the output of `curl "http://example.com:6123/something?param=123"`?

Comment: It says curl: (7) Failed to connect: Connection timed out

Comment: And how about `dig example.com`?

Comment: I get NXDOMAIN. I'm starting to suspect the service can only be accessed from my local network :(

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Domain is not available from the outside, only from local network. Thanks Dustin Ingram!